# Running a Java program from Adobe AIR's native process

Tags: java, air, adobe

I've use Adobe native process to run java program from my air app. Here the code and it works fine. But i should write absolute path to java runtime for that:

/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java.

If user installed java runtime in diff folder, or have diff version then this code would not work. How i can detect where java were installed or maybe there is another right way to run java applications from air applications? If i run java library from terminal command line then i could just write "java -jar pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar" etc. and it runs fine.

```
 private function convertPdf2Txt():void{
        var arg:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;
        arg.push("-jar");
        arg.push(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar").nativePath);
        arg.push("ExtractText"); 
        arg.push("-force");
        arg.push(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Data/1.pdf").nativePath);
        arg.push(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Data/1.txt").nativePath);

        var fjava:File = new File("/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java");
        if (fjava.exists==false){
            Alert.show("Can't find Java Runtime in default folder.","Idea Rover",mx.controls.Alert.OK, null,null,imgInfo);
            return;
        }

        var npInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo;
        npInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        npInfo.executable = fjava;
        npInfo.arguments = arg;

        var nativeProcess:NativeProcess;
        nativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT,onNativeProcessExit);
        nativeProcess.start(npInfo);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute path is:

- Mac OS: /usr/bin/java
- Win OS: (default)

  - 64bit : C:\Program Files\Java
  - 32bit : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java

Answer (score 0):

rather than popping up an Alert, you could open a file selection dialog, using [File.browseForOpen()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForOpen%28%29).  then, the File you want is contained in the event passed by the Event.SELECT handler.  this flow seems standard for applications i've used that need to access other applications, but aren't sure where to find their executables.

```
var npInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
// setup npInfo, nativeProcess...

var fjava:File = new File("/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java");
if (!fjava.exists) {
    fjava.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
    fjava.browseForOpen("Where is Java located?");
}

private function onFileSelected (evt:Event) :void {
    npInfo.executable = evt.target;
    nativeProcess.start(npInfo);
    fjava.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
}
```

of course, you can use the same logic to find the file java needs to launch as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to determine where the Java binaries are by looking at the JAVA_HOME environment variable.  I'd like to do the same thing as you're doing, so I'll post more after I do more research.

Comment: No, I ended up switching to different technologies